# Open port 4000 for Trader Workstation in Fedora

Tags: fedora, firewall, port

I have installed Trader WorkStation by Interactive Brokers. However, the program does not run, with assistance from support I found that the firewall is the problem.

The servers (several primary and backup servers) listen on port 4000 and 4001 (in case of SSL connection). The site recommends the following command for testing:

```
telnet zdc1.ibllc.com 4000
```

If I try to run that, I get

```
Trying 217.192.86.32...
telnet: connect to address 217.192.86.32: Connection timed out
```

I already tried to activate the port:

```
$ firewall-cmd --list-ports
1025-65535/udp 1025-65535/tcp
$ firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=4000/tcp --permanent
success
$ firewall-cmd --reload
success
```

The testing is still negative. `Connection timed out.`

How can I open the port? It would be ideal to restrict the access only to a few servers that are mentioned on the site. I have Fedora 27. Thank you.

EDIT (Solved): Thanks to @mark-plotnick. The problem was in the settings of the router - when I connect elsewhere, the connection works. As I will move in a few days, it's not necessary to open the ports in the router.

Comment: Fedora typically allows all outgoing connections. Do you have one or more routers to go through before you get to your ISP? They may have firewall rules, too. Does `traceroute zdc1.ibllc.com` succeed?

Comment: No, it fails. I get only to the first hop ` 1  gateway (192.168.0.1)  2.662 ms  5.300 ms  5.254 ms` followed by asterisks only. Is the problem within my router?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Fedora, but according to [the documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/19/html/Security_Guide/sec-Open_Ports_in_the_firewall-CLI.html):

> List all open ports for a zone, for example dmz, by entering the
>   following command as root:
>
> ```
> # firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --list-ports
> ```
>
> To add a port to a zone, for example to allow TCP traffic to port 8080
>   to the dmz zone, enter the following command as root:
>
> ```
> # firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --add-port=8080/tcp
> ```
>
> To make this setting permanent, add the --permanent option and reload
>   the firewall. To add a range of ports to a zone, for example to allow
>   the ports from 5060 to 5061 to the public zone, enter the following
>   command as root:
>
> ```
> # firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5060-5061/udp
> ```
>
> To make this setting permanent, add the **--permanent** option and
>   reload the firewall.

That should be a good first pass on getting IB to work. For what it's worth, this was the first [search result](https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=fedora+open+port+&cat=web&pl=ext-ff&language=english) for "fedora open ports".

Comment: I already tried this but with no results. `$ firewall-cmd --list-ports
1025-65535/udp 1025-65535/tcp`

Comment: @neydek That (and anything else you've tried) should be included in your original question then.